# scratch-blocks@0.1.0 prepublish: `python build.py && webpack`

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, reactjs, npm

i am running scratch-blocks at linux terminal

https://scratch.mit.edu/discuss/topic/289503/

I got the problem which is

python build.py && webpack

scratch-blocks@0.1.0 prepublish: python build.py && webpack

could you give me a help?

```
npm WARN prepublish-on-install As of npm@5, `prepublish` scripts are deprecated.
npm WARN prepublish-on-install Use `prepare` for build steps and `prepublishOnly` for upload-only.
npm WARN prepublish-on-install See the deprecation note in `npm help scripts` for more information.

> scratch-blocks@0.1.0 prepublish /mnt/e/hit and try/scratch/scratch-blocks
> python build.py && webpack

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "build.py", line 39, in <module>
  raise Exception("Blockly build only compatible with Python 2.x.\n"
Exception: Blockly build only compatible with Python 2.x.
You are using: 3.8.5 (default, Jul 28 2020, 12:59:40)
[GCC 9.3.0]
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! scratch-blocks@0.1.0 prepublish: `python build.py && webpack`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the scratch-blocks@0.1.0 prepublish script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/soumitya/.npm/_logs/2020-11-05T05_06_36_269Z-debug.log
```

Comment: By reading the traceback, it is easy to identify the problem: `Blockly build only compatible with Python 2.x.`

Answer (score 0):

when i set python2 as default it works:

Set priority for default python in Linux terminal by adding this:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3 10
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2 1
```

Here, we set `python3` to have priority 10 and `python2` to priority 1. This will make `python3` the default python. If you want Python2 as default then make a priority of python2 higher then python3

Answer (score 0):

You can run this command in Linux terminal

```
apt-get install -y nginx git python-setuptools python-dev
```